# Where are default compose-key bindings stored?

Tags: x11, compose-key

I recently discovered the [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). It's wonderful to type <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> and get a Unicode right-arrow (→).

I know I can [add my own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103649/adding-custom-compose-key-sequences), but where can I find a complete chart of the defaults?

---

The largest list I could find is [this one at *freedesktop.org*](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre). However, it seems imperfect too: For example, it lists a combination <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> as producing "reversed hand with middle finger extended", which—quite disappointingly—doesn't work for me…

Is there somewhere these are stored on my actual live system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the compose table used by your system at the same place programs do: it's a text file. To locate it, you can run something like

```
strace xterm -e true 2>&1 | grep -i compose
```

For example, the relevant lines on Debian wheezy are:

```
open("/home/gilles/.XCompose", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose", O_RDONLY) = 5
```

This demonstrates several things:

- To define your own table, put it in the file `~/.XCompose`. Actually, you can override this location by setting the environment variable `XCOMPOSEFILE`.
- The location of the system table is listed in `/usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir`. This file can list different tables for different locales.

<kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> is a [recent addition](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/commit/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre?id=c0670e5d3ae330e611ecb05303d579a4f8a3d114), the corresponding character is itself a recent addition to Unicode.

Comment: Dang, I forgot `strace` existed. Great detective work. Thank you!

Comment: Just a note about using `~/.Xcompose`.  Unless you are copying a system Compose file into your `~/.XCompose` file, make sure you put `include "%L"` at the top of it before your custom Compose lines.  That way you can reference the locale specific system Compose file under `/usr/share/X11/locale`.  This is slightly better in that you are always referencing the latest installed system Compose file for your locale and your custom Compose file is cleaner as it only contains your definitions.  You can find out about `%L` by using `man Compose` from a terminal.