# Is it possible to type μ on the bash command line without copying and pasting?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, input-method

This may seem a bit of a strange question, but it occurred to me that when typing a command such as the following, I always have to copy and paste the character from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)).

```
echo '5 μs' >> /tmp/Output
```

**Is there a way to input such a character directly using an escape sequence on keyboard shortcut on a standard English keyboard?**

For example, in `Vim`, one can do `C-k,m*` to produce this character.

Comment: Standard (UK) English keyboard with Compose enabled. à á å ä æ § ¥ € £ ß µ. And many others.

Comment: Note that the character actually used here in the question title and body is U+00B5, the SI prefix in `μs`.

Comment: Both `M-x set-input-method RET greek` and `C-x RET C-\ greek` will set emacs to a greek keyboard where the usual place for `m` is the greek letter `μ` (and alpha is `a` beta is `b`, etc.).

Comment: @JdeBP Actually the question characters are U+03bc (the Greek ones), not U+00b5 (the micro ones). But the **use** is obviously **micro** as in **micro-seconds**. So, the question is actually conflicting on this issue. Anyway, we've got solutions for everything now.

Comment: I did copy and paste the question text to check.  The characters came out as U+00B5 here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there are at least this four (five?) ways:

1. AltGr
   Make your keyboard layout `English (international AltGr dead keys)`.
   Then the **right** <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key. Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> will generate a µ. Many other keys also generate other characters: AltGr-s for `ß`, and Shift-AltGr-s for `§`.

   There is a separate keyboard layout for the console (the true consoles at <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>F6</kbd>) and one for the GUI in X. Changing either depends on your distro (CentOS, Fedora, Debian, etc.) and Display manager (gnome, kde, xfce, etc.). For example, [installing `xfce4-xkb-plugin`](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin) will allow a button on a panel to configure the keyboard and switch between several keyboard layouts for X in XFCE.
2. Compose
   Make some key the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key. Then, presing <kbd>Compose</kbd>, releasing it, pressing <kbd>/</kbd>, releasing it, and then <kbd>u</kbd> will generate a µ.

   Defining a `Compose` key is usually done with `xkb` or with a keyboard layout applet.
   For example, in Gnome usually [available at Region & Language](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-layouts.html.en) section, or maybe, [Switch Keyboard Layout Easily](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/06/switch-keyboard-layout-easily-in-gnome-shell.html).
3. Unicode
   There is a generic way to type **any** Unicode character (if your console supports it). Yes any codepoint of [the 1,111,998 possible characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928054/9110606) (visible if your font(s) could draw them). Press, as one chord (at the same time) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>, release them (Probably, an underlined u̲ will appear), then type `b5` which is the Unicode codepoint (always in Hex) for the character. And to end, type space or enter (at least).
4. Readline
   In a bash prompt (as you tagged the question) is possible to use readline to generate a µ (`mu`).

   ```
    bind '"\eu": "µ"'
   ```

   Or add the line:

   ```
    "\eu": "µ"
   ```

   to `~/.inputrc`, read it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> or start a new bash shell (execute `bash`) and when you type:

   <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>

   An `µ` will appear.
5. Input method
   Probably too much for a short answer like this.

---

A mistake:
Technically, the character requested in the question was Unicode `\U3bc` while this answer has provided solutions for `\Ub5`. Yes, they are different, my mistake, sorry.

```
 $ unicode $(printf '\U3bc\Ub5')
 U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
 UTF-8: ce bc UTF-16BE: 03bc Decimal: &#956; Octal: \01674
 μ (Μ)
 Uppercase: 039C
 Category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
 Unicode block: 0370..03FF; Greek and Coptic
 Bidi: L (Left-to-Right)

 U+00B5 MICRO SIGN
 UTF-8: c2 b5 UTF-16BE: 00b5 Decimal: &#181; Octal: \0265
 µ (Μ)
 Uppercase: 039C
 Category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
 Unicode block: 0080..00FF; Latin-1 Supplement
 Bidi: L (Left-to-Right)
 Decomposition: <compat> 03BC
```

And technically, the only valid solutions are number 3 and 4. In 3 the Unicode number could be changed from `b5` to `3bc` to get even this **Greek** character. In 4 just copy the correct character and done.

#### Not in my defense, but

1. Both `b5` and `3bc` have as Uppercase `39c`. So, both are the lowercase of MU.
2. Both look very, very similar (probably the same glyph from the font):

[image]

## Alternatives.

1. AltGr

   Its quite possible [and already done](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2015/03/26/a-new-nice-trick-for-the-linux-keyboard-greek-letters/) by changing the AltGr-g (with xkb) to:

   ```
    key <AC05>  { [         g,          G,       dead_greek,   dead_greek ]};
   ```

   And then typing `AltGr-g m` to get a true greek-mu.
2. Compose

   The Compose table is incorrect, even the Greek Compose file (/usr/share/X11/locale/el_GR.UTF-8/Compose) lists:

   ```
    <Multi_key> <slash> <u>                 : "µ"   mu
    <Multi_key> <u> <slash>                 : "µ"   mu
    <Multi_key> <slash> <U>                 : "µ"   mu
    <Multi_key> <U> <slash>                 : "µ"   mu
   ```

   Those compositions as `Greek`, which they are not.

   The correct solution for compose is to [include an ~/.XCompose for greek](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787113/compose-dead-greek-with-compose-key) and reboot.
3. Unicode

   Works as posted, with unicode number `3bc`
4. Readline

   Works as posted, change the effective character to any wanted.

Comment: Method 3 unicode, does not work for me.

Comment: Older debian didn't have this option. Which distro and which console? konsole, gnome-terminal, terminator, etc ? @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: I just want to know why do method 3 work. It doesn't seem to be related to X's keyboard layout or Xcb.

Comment: No it is not related to keyboard, xkb, input method, or desktop shortcut. It is an option that some (many, it seems now) programs provide/support, something like using some specific set of colors to match TTY colors. [Not long ago some terminals didn't have it, yet](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/3_1095339/how-can-i-input-unicode-characters-in-konsole-on-kubuntu-18-04/). Most do now. @神秘德里克

Comment: Very good answer in theory, but every glyph you use here is `µ` (micro, U+00B5), not what was asked in the question, `μ` (mu, U+03BC).

Comment: Yes, you are technically correct. Thanks !!. Added some descriptions and **solutions**. @Sparhawk

Comment: You were actually right the first time, and Sparhawk is wrong. The `μ` in `μs` in the question is indeed U+00B5.

Comment: …and the context calls for micro: `echo '5 μs'`

Comment: By the way, `compose` - `m` - `u` also works and is perhaps easier to memorize than `compose` - `/` - `u`. Both do the micro version.

Comment: I believe that everyone has gain by @Sparhawk comment because now we have solutions for everything. The answer got better, I learnt a couple of things. Please, look for the bright side not who is to blame.

Comment: @spectras Yep, `compose-mu` is easier to remember, but I like `compose-g-m` for Greek-Mu better (just personal preference, not that it means much).

Comment: On the note of the two characters, they are typographically equivalent, but the Unicode standard is encoding a semantic difference.  The lower codwpoint is a mathematical symbol, while the upper one is a letter from the Greek alphabet.  The semantic difference usually doesn't matter, but it might if the text is being processed beyond just displaying it on screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you [enable your compose key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Configuring_compose_key), you can print this symbol with the <kbd>compose</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> sequence, like so: µ

The full range of symbols available, and their respective key sequences, is [documented on the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable).

Comment: Your answer gives `µ` (micro, U+00B5), not what was asked in the question, `μ` (mu, U+03BC).

Comment: @Sparhawk Guilty; but I can't tell them apart.

Comment: `Compose` `*` `m` if you use something like https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/blob/master/dotXCompose

Answer (score 3):

## Using input methods

CIN-file input methods are usable in X11 and in my user-space virtual terminals.  One of the commonly-collected ones, `greek.cin`, has the mu character.  One simply enters `m` (lower case) and it is the only conversion.

One can modify `greek.cin` to add micro, providing a second conversion, although visually it will be quite confusing, making it hard to select the correct one during conversion selection, if they both map from `m`.  A better conversion would map `micro` to U+00B5:

```
micro    μ
```

## Using the ISO 9995 common secondary group

Your X11 keyboard map or your virtual terminal might not implement this, but if it does there is a standard country-independent key *sequence* (of *two* key chords) for the mu character defined by ISO/IEC 9995: <kbd>⇨ Group 2 Select</kbd> B07

- <kbd>⇨ Group 2 Select</kbd> is conventionally the chord <kbd>⇧ Level 2 Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇮ Level 3 Shift</kbd> because the USB HID specification and others lack a code for a proper <kbd>⇨ Group 2 Select</kbd> key and such a key does not exist on most keyboards.
- <kbd>⇮ Level 3 Shift</kbd> is usually engraved <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> or <kbd>⇮ AltGr</kbd> on 105/106/107/109-key keyboards or <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> on 104-key keyboards.
- B07 is the standard ISO/IEC 9995 notation for a physical position on row "B" and column "07", and the key there is usually engraved <kbd>M</kbd>.

Where implemented, this so-called *common secondary group* of ISO/IEC 9995 is not supposed to vary by the selected country's layout, and is always available.

However, there is no common secondary group sequence for the micro prefix character.

## Using whatever chord is defined in your keyboard layout

The specifics of keyboard layouts are beyond the scope of this answer, and there are plenty of answers here dealing with them.

### Précis:

There is a keyboard layout for X11 applications, there is a possibly related keyboard layout for kernel virtual terminals (if your operating system has such), and there is are keyboard layouts for user-space virtual terminals (if you are using such).  Layouts generally provide such characters as a chord with <kbd>⇧ Level 2 Shift</kbd> or <kbd>⇮ Level 3 Shift</kbd> in conjunction with a main keypad key.

Some X11 keyboard maps furthermore define (as an optional addendum) a *compose key* which begins key sequences (of multiple key chords) that map to such characters.  In the [conventional X11 composition set, as documented by David Monniaux years ago](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/i18n/compose/en_US.UTF-8.html), the mu character is the sequence <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> or the sequence <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>.  Note that it is conflated with the micro prefix character.

Consult your VT and X11 keyboard maps for information about what chord is mapped, if any.  Check your configuration for whether you have enabled the compose key option in X11.

### Examples:

The `ch`, `de`, `it`, `nl`, and `no` virtual terminal keyboard maps in FreeBSD provide the mu character as the chord <kbd>⇮ Level 3 Shift</kbd>+B07 (<kbd>M</kbd>):

```
% sed -n -e '2,5p;/0xb5/p' /usr/share/vt/keymaps/de.kbd                                                         /usr/share/vt/keymaps [pts/4.10009.1]
#                                                         alt
# scan                       cntrl          alt    alt   cntrl lock
# code  base   shift  cntrl  shift  alt    shift  cntrl  shift state
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
  050   'm'    'M'    cr     cr     0xb5   0xb5   cr     cr      C
%
```

But other maps either do not have it or define a different chord.  In the `fr` keyboard map it is <kbd>⇧ Level 2 Shift</kbd>+C12 (EUROPE1):

```
% sed -n -e '2,5p;/0xb5/p' /usr/share/vt/keymaps/fr.kbd                                                         /usr/share/vt/keymaps [pts/4.10011.1]
#                                                         alt   
# scan                       cntrl          alt    alt   cntrl lock
# code  base   shift  cntrl  shift  alt    shift  cntrl  shift state
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
  043   '*'    0xb5   nop    nop    '#'    '~'    nop    nop     O
%
```

And it is not mapped in the `uk` keyboard map at all.  Nor do any of them have the micro prefix character.

## Other methods

Other methods are specific to application input handling libraries or to particular terminal emulators, whereas input methods and X11/VT keyboard maps are not application-specific.

Some terminal emulators provide other ways of entering characters, by their Unicode code points.  Readline can of course be configured to map input sequences to this character, as also can ZLE.  And you have already mentioned VIM in the question.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[terminal resources](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/terminal-resources.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  *[Typing the motto of Vietnam on an ISO 9995-3 keyboard](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/iso-9995-3-motto-vietnam.html)*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  *[Japanese input methods in nosh user-space virtual terminals](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/japanese-input-methods.html)*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- [Where are default compose-key bindings stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164795/5132)
- [Changing the keyboard layout/mapping on both the console (tty) and X in an X/console agnostic way?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479673/5132)