# Add custom compose key sequence (not working)

Tags: gnome, input-method, compose-key

I use [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) 7.0 LTS (Comes with [GNOME 3](http://www.gnome.org/) [Flashback](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback)). I visited some post like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103649/66803) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/47496). on the topic about adding custom compose key sequence.

I set Menu Key as Compose Key:

[image: screenshot]

I created `~/.Xcompose` containing:

```
$ cat ~/.Xcompose 
include "%L"   # import the default Compose file for your locale
<Multi_key> <r> <r>     : "ñ" U00F1
```

Also added `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` at the end of `~/.profile`.
***I tried after logging out and login back, also restarting many times but it is not working.***

The default compose key sequences (`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`) e.g. <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> = ß is working fine.

I also tried to add custom key sequence:-

```
<Multi_key> <s> <d>                 : "ñ"   U00F1
```

At the end of `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` but it is also not working.

Thus, Why my custom compose sequence is not working? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I've installed [uim](http://packages.trisquel.info/belenos/uim) and set `GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"` instead of `xim` by `export GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"` at `~/.profile` after restarting session, I found that Manually set custom key sequence in  `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` is working now. **BUT still defined sequence in `~/.Xcompose` is not working**.

BTW, what is `xim` and `uim` relation to input method and why `uim` is working and `xim` is not in my case?

Comment: See also [How can I add a custom compose key sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36168/how-can-i-get-compose-back-on-ibus/38273#38273) on sister site Ask Ubuntu

Comment: This helped me [How can I add a custom compose key sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was *my* mistake that I created `.Xcompose` instead of `.XCompose`! (see question that every times mentions `.Xcompose`).

Now all custom compose key sequences that are defined in `~/.XCompose` are working well.